# tagging on webview

Tags: iphone, xcode, tagging

Can someone help me out with about how to tag on uiwebview.Means suppose if any webpage is open and then user can tag anything he likes (like the facebook) .Hope you got my question.If someone can provide the tutorial or some code snippet , would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

of the web view delegate and create any subview (maybe a button) you like.